# How do you dry wet brown sugar clumps?

Tags: sugar, drying, brown-sugar

I have seen many people having problem with dry clumps of brown sugar, while I am having a problem of wet clumps of brown sugar. The sugar is in very moist clumps. Is there a way to dry it out to make it easy to work with as other dry minerals?

Comment: You could try spreading it out on a cookie sheet for a few hours if you're in a low humidity situation. It's winter where I'm at and our forced air heat tends to dry the air.

Comment: "... other dry minerals"? You could use the cookie sheet method of Jason Whipple's and use a low temperature oven (120 - 150F) if you are in a high-humidity location.

Comment: How are you storing it, and what is the average humidity there? It would be helpful to understand where the moisture is coming from.

Comment: In a plastic jar. 45% humidity according to Yahoo. @user3169

Comment: Then, what type of packaging do you buy the brown sugar in? I have never seen brown sugar in the US in a plastic jar.

Comment: It was bought in plastic actually. I do not live in the US @user3169

Comment: But flexible plastic sheet packaging, right? Like [this](http://www.target.com/p/c-h-golden-brown-pure-cane-sugar-2-lb/-/A-13379071)? And the sugar is dry when you buy it, right?

Comment: @user3169 actually no when I come to think about it. Just brown sugar in a plastic jar. No packaging. I guess in Israel people do not know how to pick their sugars. 
Any tips for picking good brown sugar?

Comment: What problem are you tying to solve?  What is a wet clump breaking?

Answer (score 1):

You could always recycle those food grade desiccants and put them in your brown sugar container.  In Japan, they use bincho charcoal in anything that needs to have a certain level of moisture.  Apparently the bincho charcoal is able to regulate moisture content, release stored moisture when too dry, and absorb it when it's too wet.